# If a function is continuous a.e., then it is measurable.

Tags: continuity

Is this true or wrong? How to prove it ？

Answer (score 0):

It is true.

1) One of the definitions for a continuous function is that the pre image of an open set is open.

2) A function is measurable iff $f^{-1}((-\infty, t))$ is measurable.

In our case, $f^{-1}((-\infty, t))$ is open and every open set is measurable, thus, it's measurable.

I assumed you know 1 and 2, if not I can clarify.

Comment: Here the O.P. is asking whether an *almost everywhere* continuous is measurable. Your proof only works if $f$ is continuous everywhere.